# Auto start exe application made from a bat file to start running when computer boots

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I have a batch file which is converted to a exe application I'm struggling to insert a batch code in the file so my application auto starts when windows 7 boots. 
In my batch file I tried adding REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\Scripts\Startup /v winboot /t REG_SZ /d C: Path to my application, this value is successfully added but my application does not start every time the computer boots.
I have also tried various methods but no luck

Can anyone help I need a batch command to insert into my file so it starts when the operating system starts from reboot and it should be retained following conversion to the exe application?

I have tried using this also at the start of my bat script 
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /reg.bat /t REG_SZ /F /D C:\Desktop\reg.bat 
Then my script below... It's still not loading at start up using windows 7

Answer (score 0):

That's for group policy logon/off scripts.

Try `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` (need to be admin to write here).

> **Run**

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
```

> **Description**
>
> The Run subkey of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software stores the names of programs that Windows 2000 runs at startup, for all users of the computer, each time the system starts.
>
> Each entry in the subkey represents a program. The value of the entry is the name of the executable file for the program. These entries have the following format:

```
Program Name  REG_SZ  File name
```

From *Windows 2000 Resource Kit Reference, Technical Reference to the Windows 2000 Registry in the Windows 2000 Resource Kit.*

Comment: Thank you I tried this key also the script of the application is the name of the program, I added this to my batch file converted to exe and still doesn't start at reboot !

Comment: There are policies that affect this. Type `gpresult /v /scope computer` and `gpresult /v /scope user`. Try making your exe using `iexpress` (type `iexpress` in *Start - Run* and follow the wizard.

Comment: Thanks where do I type that at start up? I have tried using this also at the start of my bat script 
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /reg.bat /t REG_SZ /F /D C:\Desktop\reg.bat 
Then my script below... It's still not loading at start up using windows 7 
Am I writing it incorrectly? As it seems to work for others?

Comment: What is reg.bat. If it's compiled it should reg.exe.

Comment: Reg.bat is the name of my bat file that is converted to exe

Comment: I use a bat script which is then converted to exe application the name of the bat scrip is reg.bat

Comment: If you want your program to run it must be an exe if turned it into one.

Comment: Hi there thank you for reply I tried that also changing to exe nothing works .. Am I adding this addition to my script correctly?

Comment: You seem to have so many things wrong. Desktop folder is rarely in the root of C:.

Comment: Is there batch command you can suggest that I can insert into my script even if I move the script to another location it still doesn't start on reboot but the it does add the key successful to the registry

Comment: You just keep asking questions, without saying what is happening. I keep asking? Reread the thread and start replying. 1/ gpresult /v /scope computer 2/ Desktop folder is rarely in the root of C:.

Comment: I have inserted the below into the top of my batch script which is Called reg.bat which is converted to reg.exe using bat to exe converter.
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /V reg.exe /t REG_SZ /F /D C:\Users\reg.exe
Then my script below... It's still not loading at start up using windows 7 .. But the keys are adding successful (I've changed location and bat to exe as you suggested)

The resultant set of polices for computer from gpresult /v /scope computer or user is N/A. 
I hope that helps as I'm at a loss

Comment: 1/ gpresult /v /scope computer 2/ Desktop folder is rarely in the root of C:.